# How to put Value from JSON API to Angular Template Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

iam newbie and i want to ask.

i want to get some value from JSON API (title, course_id, etc), and put the Value to my Template with Directive. so at Index, i can repeat my tempalate with data from the API.

How to get Value from that JSON ?

This my Code :

**my API**

```
{
"count": 1,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "url": "http://192.168.1.37:8000/api/courses/a/",
        "title": "I Love You",     <-- I want to put this Value to my Template
        "course_id": "1",
        "starting_date": "2016-10-03"
    }
           ]
}
```

**Controller demo.js**

```
demo.controller("demo", function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://192.168.1.37:8000/api/courses/'). <-- Data From my API
    then(function(response) {
        $scope.courses = response.data;
    });


    });

demo.directive("demoItemDirective", function() {
   return {
        scope : { demoInfo : "=info"},
        templateUrl : "/app/demo.tmpl"   <-- My Template
    };
   });
```

**My Template demo.tmpl**

```
<p>{{demoInfo.count}}</p>                <-- Works, count Displayed
<p>{{demoInfo.results.title}</p>         <-- Not works, title not displayed
```

**My Index.html**

```
   <div ng-repeat="group in courses | groupCount:2">
   <div ng-repeat="x in group">
        <demo-item-directive info="x"></demo-item-directive>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your post, the `result` is an array:

```
"results": [
    {
        "url": "http://192.168.1.37:8000/api/courses/a/",
        "title": "I Love You",     <-- I want to put this Value to my Template
        "course_id": "1",
        "starting_date": "2016-10-03"
    }
]
```

Thus, you can't refer to the `title` itself, you have to reference the first element:

`{{demoInfo.results[0].title}}`

Comment: Thx mate, thats Work !

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
<p>{{demoInfo.results[0].title}</p>
```

Your result contain an Array of object.

You need to access with index.